# If statement returning no such element function

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code:

```
    if(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Login"]/div/div/button[1]')!=0):
     driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Login"]/div/div/button[1]').click()
     time.sleep(randint(1,2))
```

I want this to move onto the next line if Login button is not found and therefore is equal to 0, however when I run this line of code I get the following error:

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="Login"]/div/div/button[1]"}

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. The rationale behind this code is once you have logged in, when you reopen the web page it will automatically login without you needing to press the login button therefore I need to stop the login sequence.

Comment: Please update the indentation in your code sample.

Comment: If you pass a non-existent element description to `.find_element_by_xpath()`, it's certainly not going to return zero.  `None` seems much more likely (although I'm not a selenium user, so I'm not 100% sure of what it does return).

Comment: You wouldn't even need !=0 cause it would be a boolean. It would equate to true anyways. But a try except would be more useful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath is not right, maybe.

Right click on Element then left on Inspect, click on HTML page and click CTRL+F.
In text box copy your xpath and see if it pointing on any part of HTML code,
if not try to change xpath.

Also, if you want to check is login button displayed at all, you can use

```
if(driver.findelements(By.xpath("//*[@id="Login"]/div/div/button[1]")).size>0)
{
   //code block
}
```

Comment: Element doesn't exist on the page, I want to check if it does and if it does then do something, if not move onto the next line. XPath is definitely correct if the site loads without any cookies.

Comment: Yes,I have provided you a code that will do check does element exist on page.
if(driver.findelements(By.xpath("//*[@id="Login"]/div/div/button[1]")).size>0)
{
   //code block
}